# How can I only sort thru the rows with data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that sorts the rows by a specific column, the problem is I'm manually setting the range for the number of rows to sort (i.e. A2:A174) every time I add a new row.  How can I change my code so that it sorts all the rows with data only so I don't have to go into the code and change the range every time I add a new row.

```
Sub SortByName()

  SortByName Macro

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A174") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:H174")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
Sub SortByDate()
```

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this which looks for the last cell in A to mark the range.

```
Sub SortByName()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng1 _
                                , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange rng1.Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, 8)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Application.Goto ws.[a1]
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of hard coding the column (H or 8), to select the whole range, you could consider using something like:  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select, which will select everything from A1 that forms a continual data set. This is similar to selecting A1 and then clicking Ctrl+a.

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe thx for the prompt closeout! @RobertIlbrink a couple of follow up comments (a) that wasn't specified as part of the question which asked about row size, not column length (b) using `Select` should be avoided, especially when code such as the post above is designed to be run from any sheet